# compare value from arrayvalues in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have requirement in ServiceNow application that user has manager and that manager has another manager so i'am getting New Manager ( field in table) managers and storing in array.

I am trying to match that If login user ( user logged in ServiceNow) is one of the New Manager managers

Script:

```
var NewReportsTo  ='';
NewReportsTo = current.variables.new_manager;


var item = [];

    for ( var i =1 ; i<=6;i++){
        NewReportsTo = NewReportsTo.manager;
        var Newmanager = NewReportsTo.toString();
        item.push(Newmanager);
        //var list = item.split(',');
        gs.log('Check ACL:'+Newmanager, 'TEST ACL TCR');
        if(item.indexOf(gs.getUserID())){
            gs.log('Check ACL:'+current.sys_id, 'TEST ACL INSIDE TCR');
            answer = true;
        }

    }
```

`getUserID()` is the login user and item array has all the manager for New manager field

Comment: I can't figure out what your specific question is.

Comment: So, what values do you want to compare?

Comment: When you tried, is there anything that went wrong or is blocking you from continuing? Your post isn't telling that you need something at all. Please improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.indexOf()` returns the first index at which the given item can be found in the array, or -1 if it's not found.

You should change your code to:

```
if(item.indexOf(gs.getUserID() != -1)){
   ...
}
```